# How do I block a UserAgent that is only Mozilla?

Tags: htaccess

How do I block a UserAgent that is only Mozilla?

**URL:** 64.79.100.26.webcrawler.link

**This does NOT work:**  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mozilla;\)$ [NC,OR]`

IP Range was blocked, but I want to block the UA too ;)

Comment: Can you provide the UA exactly as you see it in your logs?? That might help to get a precise answer.

Comment: /about/
Http Code: 200 
Date: Jun 15 13:54:36  
Http Version: HTTP/1.1  
Size in Bytes: 3007
Referer: - Agent: Mozilla

Comment: Updated answer- JIC.

Answer (score 1):

If the UA is Mozilla only, then this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla$ [NC,OR]
```

This should not block any other UA string.

However, I am not in favor of blocking by such a common UA string. It could possibly block a valid user. I would prefer to block by IP address or IP address block.

### Block by IP Address:

Apache .htaccess File

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^64\.79\.100\.11$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Cisco Firewall

```
access-list deny-64-79-100-11-32 deny ip 64.79.100.11 any
permit ip any any
```

Nginx

Edit nginx.conf and insert include blockips.conf; if it does not exist. Edit blockips.conf and add the following:

```
deny 64.79.100.11;
```

Microsoft IIS Web Server

```
<rule name="abort ip address 64.79.100.11/32" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^64\.79\.100\.11$" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Windows netsh ADVFirewall Firewall

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="block-ip-64-79-100-11-32" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=64.79.100.11/32
```

### Block by IP Address Block:

IP Address Range:

```
64.79.96.0 - 64.79.111.255
```

NetMask:

```
Block: 64.79.96.0/20
Base Address: 64.79.96.0
Broadcast Address: 64.79.111.255
Net Mask: 255.255.240.0
Host Mask: 0.0.15.255
Bits: 20
Size: 4096
2nd Element: 64.79.96.2
Block by IP Address Block
```

Apache .htaccess File

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^64\.79\.([0-1]+[0-1]+[90123456789]+[67890123456789]+)\.([0-2]+[0-5]+[0-5]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Cisco Firewall

```
access-list deny-64-79-96-0-20 deny ip 64.79.96.0 0.0.15.255 any
permit ip any any
```

Nginx

Edit nginx.conf and insert include blockips.conf; if it does not exist. Edit blockips.conf and add the following:

```
deny 64.79.96.0/20;
```

How to block by IP address block using Linux IPTables Firewall.

**Note: Use with caution.

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s 64.79.96.0/20 -j DROP
```

Microsoft IIS Web Server

```
<rule name="abort ip address block 64.79.96.0/20" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
   <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^64\.79\.111\..*$" />
  </conditions>
 <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Windows netsh ADVFirewall Firewall

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="block-ip-block-64-79-96-0-20" dir=in interface=any action=block remoteip=64.79.96.0/20
```

Comment: Works Like A Cham with the Firefox UserAgent Switcher - great for testing junk  8)

Comment: Thanks but it's a Linux Server on a shared host.

Comment: I like blocking by UA too because baidu & yandex both has servers in the USA too.  These idiots will try all sorts of junk to access my site digitalocean.com, datashack.net, linode.com.  The last 2 try and hack my site every week!

Comment: These could be compromised servers. Another alternative is a host that is permissive and leases space to a hacker or spammer. BYW- the apparent IP address sub-domain resolves to another IP address (in this case within the same IP address block). This is also common. It pays to double-check these. This is often a sign of a bad host or subscriber block.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but I just sleep better blocking Larry, Moe and Curly from doing anything stupid ;}

Comment: Larry, Moe, Curly are not the ones I worry about, it is Snidely Whiplash that keeps me up at night!!